# Include clause in jooq prepared statement conditionally

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Hi I am using JOOQ to build a SQL statement in my java application. I need to include an or clause in my statement under a certain condition and omit under the other.
e.g.

```java
org.jooq.Query ps =  select(field("q.*"))
                            .from(table("QUEUES q"))
                            .where(field("q.APPLICATION").eq("APP1"));
```

I then need to unclude an or part to the query depending on some other variable..

```java
org.jooq.Query ps =  select(field("q.*"))
                            .from(table("QUEUES q"))
                            .where(field("q.APPLICATION").eq("APP1"))
                            .or(field("q.APPLICATION").eq("APP2"));
```

I can't figure out how to do this without having two separate statements, one including the or statement and one without. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note, you can provide your own answer to your own question, rather than editing the question itself. It will be easier to understand for a future visitor of the question

Comment: For the record, the relevant section of the manual about using jOOQ for dynamic SQL is here: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is use the extensions of `SelectConditionStep` which will allow you to break up the query into individual steps and use a flag as a means to attach only one specific extension of `SelectConditionStep` to the query.

Given your query and a flag (`boolean` - to separate the extension of `SelectConditionStep`to be used) called for e.g. `checkBothApps`.

```
boolean checkBothApps = false;

org.jooq.SelectJoinStep<R> joinStep =  select(field("q.*"))
                        .from(table("QUEUES q"));

org.jooq.SelectConditionStep<R> conditionStep = joinStep.where(field("q.APPLICATION").eq("APP1"));

if (checkBothApps) {
  // This condition will be added to the join step.
  joinStep.or(field("q.APPLICATION").eq("APP2"));
}
```

Edit: Tested code.

Comment: Whgile this works perfectly fine, it is usually better to store the entire `Condition` in a local variable, rather than the `XYZ..Step` types.

Comment: Thank you for the tip Lukas.  Would it be possible to further explain the reasoning for this so as to understand better please!
Edit: Am I right to assume that you are referring to something similar to the OP answer below?

Comment: Yes, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50289420/521799) shows what I meant. The advantage of that approach is that 1) it is operating on immutable API elements, 2) it is far more composable and usable for more complex dynamic SQL constructions, 3) it is more readable. 4) At some point, your approach will be insufficient and you'll have to revert to the other. Ideally, you should never need to explicitly reference any API with a `Step` suffix from client code. I guess that would be a good remark in the Javadocs to increase visibility: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7478

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Koshux
I did it like this...

```java
Condition whereClause = field("q.APPLICATION").eq("APP1");
if(bothApps){
    whereClause = whereClause.or(field("q.APPLICATION").eq("APP2"));
}
org.jooq.Query ps =  select(field("q.*"))
                     .from(table("QUEUES q"))
                     .where(whereClause);
```